# How to generate SHA3-256 in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, sha-3

Is there an option to calculate SHA3-256 hashes in .NET Core? The goal is to recreate the `isChecksumAddress` [util function in web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/master/lib/utils/utils.js#L422)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing that now with pure dotnet core.

> It's been on the watch list since it was announced. Since we don't implement cryptographic algorithms within .NET we're waiting on support from the underlying platforms (Windows CNG, Apple Security.framework, and OpenSSL).

See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16485).

But you might have a better luck with BouncyCastle. It has an implementation [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/096c4894f62b7f4178ab869ec342e9351bd198dd/crypto/src/crypto/digests/SHA3Digest.cs) but I don't know if it is out yet (in nuget).

Answer (score 9):

If you require a SHA-3 implementation in .NET your options are as follows (at the time of writing):

1. Wait for [.NET 8.0](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20342) which will ship with FIPS-202 implementations. Note that these will use the operating system's underlying crypto APIs, and therefore not all operating systems will be supported. As far as I know, managed fallback implementations are not provided.
2. Use [SHA3.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3.Net/) which is implemented using BouncyCastle. Note that this pulls down over 14MB in dependencies due to BouncyCastle, and implements the Keccak SHA-3 standard, rather than FIPS-202, and will therefore yield different hashes to the APIs that will ship with .NET 8.0
3. Use [OnixLabs.Security.Cryptography](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OnixLabs.Security.Cryptography/) which is implemented using the .NET cryptography APIs and has no upper dependency chain, therefore roughly 80KB in dependencies (in contrast to ~14MB for SHA3.NET), and implements the FIPS-202 standard, and will therefore yield identical hashes to the APIs that will ship with .NET 8.0. This includes all FIPS-202 SHA-3 variants: SHA3-224, SHA3-256, SHA3-384, SHA3-512, SHAKE-128, and SHAKE-256

Comment: This package has been deprecated as it is legacy and is no longer maintained.

Comment: @creanium Thank you for pointing this out. I have updated the links with the latest repository and nuget packages, which are actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **SHA3.Net** that is a SHA3 wrapper of the BouncyCastle implementation, implementing System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SHA3.Net/